# How does the team buff work when you lose a player?

Tags: robocraft-infinity

When playing a multiplayer match in *Robocraft Infinity*, if a player drops from the match, the rest of their remaining team gets "buffed".

How does this buff work? From my own experience, my damage numbers seem to be bigger when other players leave, but is it just damage, or health too?

Also, does the buff scale if more players leave the match? The voice over definitely says the team has been buffed again, but I thought it may just be the stock message for when someone leaves.

Answer (score -1):

How the numbers work out is that whenever someone leaves, the team really only loses about 60% of a player. Each of the remaining players get buffed to get a total 40% damage increase.

This applies for each consecutive leave and it only applies to dmg as far as I know.

I think it specifies in the patch notes aswell.

Comment: Seems legit, tho i could not find confirmation in patch notes. Would be great to have a source if anyone finds one.